# Delphi: How do I clone a TJSONArray?

Tags: delphi

I have this example I would like to get the result of `GetRequest` and transfer it to `LJsonArray`. But not adding

```
function TForm1.GetRequest: TJSONArray;
var
  LResponse: IResponse;
  LJson : TJSONObject;
begin
  LResponse := TRequest
                .New.BaseURL('myEndPoint')
                .Accept('application/json')
                .Get;

  Result := LResponse.JSONValue.GetValue<TJSONArray>('structure'); 
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LJsonArray : TJSONArray;
begin
 LJsonArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    LJsonArray.Add(GetRequest); //<-
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(LJsonArray.ToJSON);
  finally
    LJsonArray.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Only do `Memo1.Lines.Add( GetRequest().ToJSON );` and nothing else. Don't create it.

Comment: @Amigo `GetRequest()` is returning a pointer to an array that is owned by the function and gets destroyed when the function exits, thus the need for cloning.

Comment: @DaianeSantana: Please note that we don't add tags like "Solved" or "Sorted out" to a question's title or body when an answer has been found. Instead, you indicate this by *accepting* an answer. Soon you'll be able to accept Remy's answer (if you aren't already able to do so) by clicking the large check mark to the left of his answer.

Answer (score 2):

`TJSONArray` has a [`Clone`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONArray.Clone) method:

```
function TForm1.GetRequest: TJSONArray;
var
  LResponse: IResponse;
begin
  LResponse := TRequest
                .New.BaseURL('myEndPoint')
                .Accept('application/json')
                .Get;

  Result := TJSONArray(LResponse.JSONValue.GetValue<TJSONArray>('structure').Clone); 
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LJsonArray : TJSONArray;
begin
 LJsonArray := GetRequest;
  try
    Memo1.Text := LJsonArray.ToJSON;
  finally
    LJsonArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```